# multiple Onactivityresult method in Android

Tags: java, android

I added `onClick()` button in fragment to display the result. I also added `onActivityResult()` method in `MyActivity`. I want to add `onClick()` button in more fragments and also show results.

In that case how I should write multiple `onActivityResult()` method in activity?

Below is my code for `OnActivityResultmethod`:

```
    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.zing);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
            scanIntegrator.initiateScan();

        }


    });
 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, 
     data);
Fragment fragment = this.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.total_frame_content);
           if (fragment instanceof CustomerIdFragment) {
               if (scanResult != null) {
                   if (scanResult.getContents() == null) {
                       Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   } else {

                       //String customerSno = scanResult.getContents().substring(0, 10),
                       //       passCode = scanResult.getContents().substring(10, 14);
        Toast.makeText(this, " " + scanResult.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     //  System.out.println("Result" + scanResult.getContents());

                   }
               }

           }
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try This u can not overide method multiple time so u pas int value**

```
  startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

in on activity result

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 1){

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        //do somthing
        }

    }

    if(requestCode == 2){

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                //do somthing
        }

    }

    if(requestCode == 3){

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            //do somthing
        }

    }

}
```

**Edited Answer**
**In Your Fragment java File**

```
 private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
btChoseFile = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btChoseFile);

    btStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("*/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    });




@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"On Activity Result in fragment",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: android geeks...I am beginner to android..where should i call  startActivityForResult(intent,1); and my Onclik code in fragment....     button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.zing);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
                scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
            }


        }); like this

Comment: @Kingraj sorry  i can't understand what u want to do??

Comment: if u want to start activity for result u can also call it from your button and u can also overide onActivityResult in your fragment

Comment: no bro..OnactivityResult not triggering in fragment..I mean not working in fragment

Comment: @Kingraj may be u doing something wrong otherwise u can also use onActivityResult in fagment after your comment i retry in fragmetn its also working in fragment

Comment: bro can u send me code including onclik method..OnActivityResult method code which you tried

Comment: @Kingraj U want to show Result from fragment to activity ?

Comment: No..I added Onclick button fragment...after Onclick button.. I want show result in fragment itself

Comment: @Kingraj check My Edited Answer

Comment: Yea its working..In my code I am not able to print the result..i added Onclik code above can you tell me whats the problem

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `switch` case for that like below:

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            try {
                switch (requestCode) {
                    case REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE:

                        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {

                         //your code

                        break;
                    case PHOTO_PICKER_ID:
                        if (requestCode == PHOTO_PICKER_ID && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                           //your code
                        }

                        break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("krvrrusbviuritiribtr", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call **startActivityForResult(intent,requestCode);**, you just need to use different requestCode. This number will be send to the **onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent)**

Create some constants for the request in your activity (call it MyActivity).

```
public class MyActivity{
    private static final int REQUEST_ONE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_TWO = 2;

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {  
    //Management of the result, see below
    }
}
```

Use the constant corresponding to the request calling.

```
//startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
```

In you first fragment, you will use

```
public void clickButton(View v){
    startActivityForResult(intent,MyActivity.REQUEST_ONE);
}
```

In the second fragment, you will use

```
public void clickButton(View v){
    startActivityForResult(intent,MyActivity.REQUEST_TWO);
}
```

Then you just need to implements the result method in the activity to take care of the requestCode value to execute the correct code. Using a switch or if else conditions. There are more possibilities (using some pattern) but the easiest are those.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {  
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_ONE){
        // the code for request one
    } else if(requestCode == REQUEST_TWO){
        // the code for request two
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }
}
```

or with a switch

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    switch(requestCode)
    case REQUEST_ONE:
        // the code for request one
        break;
    case REQUEST_TWO:
        // the code for request two
        break;
    default:
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }
}
```

If you have too much request, create one method for each requests, this will keep the result method more readable.

Comment: Even if my answer is similar than the others, nobody explain how to set requestCode so I decide to correct that.

Comment: Ok bro..no need to write anything in fragment ha?

Comment: and where should i call startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_ONE);

Comment: The fragment don't need anything for this, except maybe an update of some informations. The method with REQUEST_ONE is just a example on how to call a specific request with a code. These should be called from your onClick method in specific fragment. Just be sure to use different **requestCode** to manage the result correctly. I edited this part in my answer to be more specific.

Comment: AxelH..if i add..startActivityForResult(intent,MyActivity.REQUEST_ONE);..on fragment..in onclikmethod its showing error..in intent place..i added onclik method in my code above

Comment: Of course, you are using an API here. What is this API providing IntentIntegrator ? But it's seems you have found your answer...

Comment: com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;

Comment: Then read the doc. This is explained in it. And you used it... Since you have accepted an answer, I see you problem as solved.